# Are the consecutive days badges site specific?

Tags: support, badges

Do I need to visit all of the SE sites everyday that I want to obtain the Enthusiast, consecutive days badge for? Or does interacting with just one count for all of them?

Comment: Visiting only one site wouldn't be enthousiastic or fanatic at all.

Comment: so visiting the same page on that same site will work? for example, if I write a script that visits this everyday for 30 days... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160989/consecutive-days-site-specific

Comment: If you think writing a script to achieve a badge makes you an Enthusiast, then by all means go for it. Don't be surprised if you get banned for running an unauthorized script, though.

Comment: @ÄlËverett [not sure anyone pays attention](http://stackexchange.com/users/145766/yibe?tab=accounts), definitely not sporting though!

Answer (score 11):

You have to visit each one separately.

Comment: And if memory serves, man does it _sting_ when you forget one...

Comment: @meta.michael Not if you don't care about those meaningless badges and just go to the site whenever you want to ask/answer questions.

Comment: @Servy I only cared when I first joined and desperately wanted my first gold badge.  I'm currently sitting on 695 consecutive days at SO, so it really isn't an issue for me anymore :)  (unless they start to offer some rare earth platinum ultra-fanatic for hitting 1000)

Comment: ...but anyway, meaningless badges which drive traffic and encourage users to visit the sites when they otherwise might not are a good thing.

Answer (score 3):

Just based on the wording of your question, I wanted to clarify... the `Enthusiast` badge is separate for each site.  If you visit Stack Overflow for 30 straight days you get the badge for Stack Overflow.  Then if you visit Unix & Linux.SE for 30 straight days, you get the badge for that site.  The badges are unique to each site.

If someone visited every SE site for 30 straight days, they either deserve a badge or a psychiatrist.

Comment: funny, but a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Or does interacting with just one count for all of them?

No, Badges/Tags/Reputation are separate for separate sites.